# Deserialize an XML string with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, deserialization

I have a problem with deserialize an XML string into C# objects. The problem is that I the result will always be null. This is my XML string which is stored into a string variable.

```xml
<objects>
  <object>
    <dateadded>1614924419</dateadded>
    <id>CF7E7B22-1D3A-4CFE-91F9-F8C5C2DB4069</id>
    <name>NorthernLights</name>
    <parentid>ED98C97F-A202-48ED-AEEA-34362508A30B</parentid>
    <type>file</type>
  </object>
  <object>
    <dateadded>1614924419</dateadded>
    <id>CF7E7B22-1D3A-4CFE-91F9-F8C5C2DB4070</id>
    <name>Northern</name>
    <parentid>ED98C97F-A202-48ED-AEEA-34362508A30C</parentid>
    <type>file</type>
  </object>
</objects>
```

Those are the classes that I have created that represent the XML document.
I suppose something is wrong  there. Can someone help me with this?

This is the class for the `objects` tag:

```cs
namespace DataContractSample.DataContract.Model
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract(Name = "objects", Namespace = "", IsReference = false)]
    [KnownType(typeof(IList<Image>))]

    public class Images
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "object", EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public IList<Image> ImageList;
    }
}
```

This is the class for the `object` tag:

```cs
namespace DataContractSample.DataContract.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [DataContract(Name = "object", Namespace = "")]
    public class Image
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
        public Guid id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="parentid")]
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name="name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "dateadded")]
        public string DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share with us how do you call the deserialize method?

Comment: var dataContractSerializerUtility = new DataContractSerializerUtility();
var sortabledataContractSerializer = new DataContractSortableSerializerUtility(dataContractSerializerUtility);
Images imageList = sortabledataContractSerializer.DeSerializer<Images>(XMLString);

Comment: Have you tried to use `List<Image>` instead of `IList<Image>`? Also `KnownTypes` attribute is weird for me here. It should be used in case of inheritance but here we don't have that.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use both List<Image> and IList<Image> and the result will be the same. I tried as you proposed to remove the KnowTypes attribute but it does not work with that change either.

Comment: In the below post I detailed the problem and showed two possible solutions. None of them relies on the `KnownTypes` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you want to deserialize the `<objects>` into a *class* and into a *property* at the same time. This won't work. Here, I present two different ways how you can solve this problem.

#### Option A

If you have an outer node around `<objects>`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<top>
  <objects>
    <object>
      <dateadded>1614924419</dateadded>
      <id>CF7E7B22-1D3A-4CFE-91F9-F8C5C2DB4069</id>
      <name>NorthernLights</name>
      <parentid>ED98C97F-A202-48ED-AEEA-34362508A30B</parentid>
      <type>file</type>
    </object>
    <object>
      <dateadded>1614924419</dateadded>
      <id>CF7E7B22-1D3A-4CFE-91F9-F8C5C2DB4070</id>
      <name>Northern</name>
      <parentid>ED98C97F-A202-48ED-AEEA-34362508A30C</parentid>
      <type>file</type>
    </object>
  </objects>
</top>
```

with this modified top level entity:

```cs
[DataContract(Name = "top", Namespace = "", IsReference = false)]
public class Images
{
    [DataMember(Name = "objects", EmitDefaultValue = false, IsRequired = true)]
    public List<Image> ImageList;
}
```

then deserialization works like a charm:

```cs
using var file = File.OpenRead("sample.xml");
using var reader = new XmlTextReader(file); 
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Images));
var data = (Images)serializer.ReadObject(reader);

Console.WriteLine(data.ImageList.Count); // Will print 2
```

#### Option B

If you don't have an outer node around `<objects>` then you can use `CollectionDataContract`:

```cs
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "objects", Namespace = "")]
public class Images: List<Image>
{

}
```

and it will work as well:

```cs
using var file = File.OpenRead("sample.xml");
using var reader = new XmlTextReader(file); 
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Images));
var data = (Images)serializer.ReadObject(reader);

Console.WriteLine(data.Count); // Will print 2
```

Comment: You are God Peter! You have solved my problem :-) Everything works fine! You should have all the thanks in the world for your commitment and help!